# CSS table-cell weird gap issue

Tags: css, html, tablecell

I have a problem with my css. There is a mysterious margin above name in second table-cell div. Please see more at: http://jsfiddle.net/xnms15uf/

```
<div id="comment">
    <div id="left_side">
        <div id="comment_picture">
            <img src="https://safebash.com/users/16556250737679624820/pictures/profile/4fa22e3ff2d4828b20d8c5561181b17b_nano.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right_side">
        <div id="comment_name">Peter</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#comment {
    width: 550px;
    height: 50px;
    display: table;
}

#left_side {
    width: 40px;
    background: #00ff00;
    display: table-cell;
}

#right_side {
    background: #ff0000;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

UPDATE:
this is what I want to achieve 
[image: vectors from illustrator]

(vectors from Illustrator)

Comment: Take off display: table-cell and margin is gone.

Comment: doesn't work in Safari

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xnms15uf/2/?

Comment: Exactly!!! thank you so much! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#right_side {
background: #ff0000;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:top;}
```

If I am understanding correctly, this is all you have to do to get the text 'Peter' to not have that spacing at the top.